# package handlers/gql.go is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/handlers/gql.go)

Tags: go, go-modules

I am trying to import local packages, I have done this before with go in my other projects. I am not sure If I am doing something wrong or I broke something in the environment I have tried go 1.14 && 1.15.

```
go mod init github.com/malikiah/go-backend
go run main.go
```

returns error:

```
handlers/gql.go: package handlers/gql.go is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/handlers/gql.go)
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I just want to be able to import local packages.

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "flag"

    //"io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "time"

    //Handlers
    "handlers/gql.go"

    //Middleware
    
    //Services

    //External Packages
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"


)

func main() {

    var wait time.Duration
    flag.DurationVar(&wait, "graceful-timeout", time.Second*15, "the duration for which the server gracefully wait for existing connections to finish - e.g. 15s or 1m")
    flag.Parse()

    port := "3000"
    // Init Router
    router := mux.NewRouter()

    // // route handlers / endpoints
    // graphiqlHandler, err := gql.NewGraphiqlHandler("/api")
    // if err != nil {
    //     panic(err)
    // }

    // router.HandleFunc("/graphql", gqlHandler())
    // router.HandleFunc("/graphiql", graphiqlHandler)
    // router.HandleFunc("/api", errorhandlers.HealthCheckHandler).Methods("GET").Name("HealthCheck")
    // router.HandleFunc("/login", userhandlers.LoginHandler).Methods("POST").Name("Login")
    // router.HandleFunc("/register", userhandlers.RegistrationHandler).Methods("POST").Name("Register")

    // router.NotFoundHandler = http.HandlerFunc(errorhandlers.NotFoundHandler)

    // router.Use(middleware.LoggingMiddleware)

    log.Println("Gopher army ready and is listening on TCP port " + port + "...")
    // Custom server
    srv := &http.Server{
        Addr: "127.0.0.1:" + port,
        // Prevents Slowloris Attacks
        WriteTimeout: time.Second * 15,
        ReadTimeout:  time.Second * 15,
        IdleTimeout:  time.Second * 60,
        Handler:      router, //Passing gorilla mux instance
    }

    go func() {
        if err := srv.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
    }()

    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    // Acceptes SIGINT for graceful shutdown.

    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt)

    // Block until it receives signal.
    <-c

    // Create a deadline to wait for.
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), wait)
    defer cancel()
    // Doesn't block if no connections, but will otherwise wait until the timeout deadline.
    srv.Shutdown(ctx)

    log.Println("shutting down...")
    os.Exit(0)

}
```

Comment: Import `github.com/malikiah/go-backend/handlers`.   Read [How to write Go code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html).

Comment: no because it just gives an error if I put it in the go.mod. They are just packages I have made for this local project. @blackgreen

Comment: @MuffinTop When I do that it actually will go and try to pull it from github which I don't have an actual repository there.

Comment: Unless I need to have a github repo for this to work but I thought you didnt

Comment: @MuffinTop ohhhhhh my god I am a idiot I have made this mistake before......

Comment: packages arent files they are folders, my god...

Comment: And stop using `go run main.go`: This is absolutely wrong! If you really cannot  bring yourself to type `go build` at least use `go run .`.

Answer (score 0):

When importing go packages you import the folder not the direct file.